# I need help for my chloride titration

Tags: experimental-chemistry, titration

I'm a 14-year-old student embarking on my first chemistry assignment. My teacher has tasked me with conducting a chloride titration of drinking water. There's just one condition: I must avoid using any hazardous substances. I've scoured the internet, but I've found only a limited number of reports. Could someone please assist me with this challenge?

Comment: Is silver nitrate regarded as hazardous by your teacher?

Comment: No, he just said the chemicals must not be carcinogenic or deadly.

Comment: For example, I am not allowed to use potassium chromate as an indicator.

Comment: Consider the Volhard or Fajans method of equivalence point detection in [Argentometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentometry). Other option could be conductometric detection.

Comment: Go to Internet Archive, search the book named Quantitative Inorganic Analysis by Vogel. It will have all the details.

Answer (score 2):

The common titration methods are explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentometry  Check to see what is available in the lab [That might also give a hint to the method you are supposed to use.] If you are also required to procure materials perhaps the money would be better spent buying a chloride specific electrode for use with your pH meter or a Hach Test kit. That is after you learn how each method works and can explain it to your teacher.

Chemists and people in general must learn how to work safely with hazardous materials and chemicals in general. Any school is an appropriate time to start and avoidance is not necessarily the best method. For all you know the water sample may be the most hazardous material encountered; talk to someone in Flint MI. I have worked for the NYDEC as an analytical chemist and have encountered samples with deadly cyanide content, pathological bacteria and many chemicals at levels higher than one drop of chromate indicator.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an aliquot to your conical flask and add a few drops of acetic acid and dichlorofluorescein indicator along with some dextrin solution.

You can then titrate against silver nitrate solution of a known concentration. The stoichiometry of the chloride to silver ion is 1:1.

This method is callled the Fajans method.